# Chrome App reading JSON as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-app

I'm building a webapp into a Chrome App and everything is working well except one issue, I load a JSON file and it reads through each of the characters as if it's a string. The native web app doesn't do this:

```
$.get('plugins.json', function (list) {
    for (var plugin in list) {
        ...code stuff...
    }
});
```

...works normally, but spits out each character of the file when run as a Chrome-App...

plugins.json:

```
{
    "MyPlugin": "plugindir"
}
```

Becomes:

```
{,",M,y,P,l,u,g,i,n...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $.getJSON() instead of $.get()?

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question with that. Strange that it works natively but not in Chrome apps, must have to do with setting the `Accept` header to `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like function

```
$.get('plugins.json', function (list) {
```

Does not know that it should work with JSON. You can try to check response headers, maybe Content-Type is wrong. Or you can try this

```
$.get('plugins.json', function (list) {
    list = JSON.parse(list);
    for (var plugin in list) {
        ....
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` only works in the Chrome App build, it breaks the native app since natively the file is interpreted as JSON. `$.getJSON` works in both cases.